# Chromecast maximum memory size

Tags: chromecast, receiver, media-source

What is the maximum video buffer size for the Chromecast Receiver? I'm rolling my own HLS-like implementation using a MediaSource and need the buffer limit.

Comment: I know very little in terms of programming for media, but I think [this Plex forum](https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/104606-my-best-video-setting-for-chromecast-and-android/) might have some info (specifically look under the "Part 2: Media Preparation" heading).

Comment: Sadly, I'm looking for something more internal/technical than this. I need the memory limit, in bytes, the chromecast supports. Something like 32*1024*1024 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovered my answer browsing Chromium source code.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/media/filters/source_buffer_platform_lowmem.cc

At the time of writing:

```
// 2MB: approximately 1 minute of 256Kbps content.
// 30MB: approximately 1 minute of 4Mbps content.

kSourceBufferAudioMemoryLimit = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
kSourceBufferVideoMemoryLimit = 30 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is this an alternative approach to memory management by catching the `QuotaExceededError` that would be thrown when calling `SourceBuffer.appendBuffer()` and then reducing the amount you try to add to the buffer from there on? Or do you need the device-specific limits for a different reason?

Comment: I suppose I could use QuotaExceededError instead. The Chromecast gets very laggy with too much memory usage, so I'd like to tread lightly.

Comment: I've since learned that with current implementations `QuotaExceededError` can't be relied upon. It's not even thrown in [Webkit](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/Modules/mediasource/SourceBuffer.cpp#L563). Also [other issues](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=28557) when relying on user agent implementations of coded frame eviction.

Comment: Oh my god, you just saved my mental health. THANK YOU!